# How to Assign php Ajax Result Value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I Just created a Simple Program to Get Entered Data through PHP Ajax.
But I want the Result which is coming from result.php page as a Variable.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text">
<button id="btn-1">
</form>
<div id="ajax-result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn-1").click(function(){
            var txt = $("input").val();
            $.post("result.php", {suggest: txt}, function(result){ 
            $("#ajax-result").html(result);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `someVariable = result;` ?  What exactly have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Please share your PHP code as well.

Comment: It is already a variable called `result`. It is a local variable to the callback function. If you want to make it a global variable then first define that variable at the global scope: `var myGlobalVar;` and assign it the value of result inside the callback function like so: `myGlobalVar = result;`

Comment: what's the status of this question? there's an answer below which to me looks like a possible solution. You didn't comment and/or accepted it, given if it was the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using $.ajax rather than $.post so that you can have more control on your AJAX calls and so you can define whether you want the 'result' variable to be a JavaScript **string** or **object**.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text">
    <button id="btn-1">
</form>
<div id="ajax-result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Define global variable to contain a copy of the AJAX return result
        var globalResult;

        function formatResultIntoHtml(result) {
            // add logic to convert your result object into html string, and return
        }

        $("#btn-1").click(function(){
            var txt = $("input").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "result.php",
                data:{
                    suggest: txt
                },
                type: "POST", // Set HTML action type
                dataType: "json", // Set expected data return type
                success:function(result) { 
                    globalResult = result; // Make result variable global
                    $("#ajax-result").html(formatResultIntoHtml(result)); // Format 
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then in your result.php file, echo a JSON string so that JQuery can auto-convert it into a Javascript object.

```
<?php

    // Add your logic to process $_GET['suggest'] here

    $dataArray = array(
        'var1' => 'data1',
        'var2' => 'data2',
        'var3' => 'data3'
    );

    header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Tells our client that we are sending JSON data
    echo json_encode($dataArray);
?>
```